How can I close a token account AND transfer all my sol to another wallet within the same transaction?
It doesn’t even need to be an automatic process, I just want a way for them to be in the same transaction.
Eg.:  https://solscan.io/tx/338UdghTgaJ3FjnWU4RU8CkrT6Xrun9jH4kuvCnUvBix3GkLivdp88QyhgrT1hKJf2BccMVmAsmuzn7ous1o25qK
Edit: Does Sol Incinerator do this?

This is possible. You can combine the two instructions(close SPL Token account and transfer SOL) in one transaction, and the runtime will execute them atomically.
async function closeAndTransferSol() {
    let mint = new PublicKey(""); // spl token account

    let tokenAcc = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(mint, signer.publicKey); //
    let lamports = (await conn.getAccountInfo(tokenAcc))?.lamports; // lamports assigned to token account

    if (!lamports) return; // ! handle this better

    let closeIX = await createCloseAccountInstruction(
        tokenAcc,
        ownerSigner.publicKey,
        ownerSigner.publicKey
    );

    let transferSolIx = await SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: signer.publicKey,
        toPubkey: new PublicKey(""),
        lamports, //
    });

    const tx = await new Transaction().add(closeIX).add(transferSolIx);
    let txHash = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(conn, tx, [ownerSigner]);
    console.log(txHash);
}

closeAndTransferSol().then().catch(console.error);

I am unsure about solincinerator support
